# Cordova Text to speech

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, text-to-speech, intel-xdk

I am trying to create an Intel XDK app with text to speech features. Can somebody give me a good Cordova plugin and a code sample that is tested and working?
 I tryed the one from W3C, but it didn't worked for me.

P.S: I am using Framework 7.

Comment: I had one working code with vanilla barebone Cordova application. Will that do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about [cordova-plugin-tts](https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts)?

It's easy to use

```
function testSpeak(){
  TTS.speak('hello, world!', function () {
    console.log('success');
  }, function (reason) {
    console.log('error', reason);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you share how to add this plugin to a phonegap project?